# Opencv contours

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

Given a binary image with multiple objects in it, I would like to enclose each object in contour. And then, I would like to calculate area inside object, followed by area inside contour. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: can you add those images?

Answer (score 2):

Use the OpenCV `findContours()` method for contours, the `contourArea()` method for contour area, and the OpenCV `Moments` class to calculate the object area.

See these pages from the OpenCV documentation site:

[Contours](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

[Contour Features](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)